# I can't run the MAUI template in Visual Studio 2022 / Dotnet 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, maui, .net-7.0

**I'm unable to even use Microsoft.Extensions with on brand new solution for *MAUI*/dotnet7/Visual Studio 2022 (release). I get tons of errors.**

For example, as the title of this:

*(Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    SensatioILH (net7.0-android)*

or
*Error  CS0012  The type 'AppCompatActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.    (net7.0-android)    ***\Platforms\Android\MainActivity.cs*

and many more.

It feels like I can't use MAUI.
I wonder if this is something related to dotnet 7 and MAUI, but I don't think that's the case. Maybe the SDK from Android? But it doesn't make too much sense in my eyes since this points to this namespace Microsoft.Extensions and not to an Android SDK version.

I've reinstalled VS, and even used an MS tool to reset/clean everything, and still no luck. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you have followed all theses : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation?tabs=vswin&view=net-maui-7.0 ?

Comment: Of course, and I've been building MAUI apps for a long time now. This happened recently, some factor is affecting this behavior. I hope some expert can help me.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio did you use? There is no `AppCompatActivity` in my project's `\Platforms\Android\MainActivity.cs`. Did you just create a new project and these errors appeared?